# Session with if statement

Tags: php, session

I have a piece of code that is not working.

```
if ($_SESSION['active'] != 2 && $_SESSION['org_id'] == 0 && $_SESSION['part_id'] == 0) 
{
    header('Location: index');
    die();
}
```

the code has to do the following things, it checks the session. and if the 'active' is not 2 and the org_id is 0 and the part_id is also zero it has to go automatically to index.php. the last part is not working. because i tested it and it keeps on the same page but the array my SESSION gives is this

```
"Array ( [notify] => OK [user] => werker@company.com [user_id] => 346 [fnln] => test2 [type] => 4 [org_id] => 108 [part_id] => 79 [active] => 2 )"
```

so it has to work. I don't know what is wrong...

Comment: put `index.php` not just `index`

Comment: [active] return 2 check your if condition , use == instead of !=

Comment: As @Twista mentionned you have to add the extension. Check out the doc http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Regarding the extension, that surely depends on the final URL.

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik no it cannot be == because when active is 2 it has not to go to index.php

Comment: @NicoHaase well you saw my array right that is the session at the moment with that session is has to go to index.php but it keeps on the same page. the page is to change your organisation when you are kicked out of one

Comment: @xmaster you should check Andrew Larsen's answer as he explains what could potentially be stopping the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That if statement you wrote won't redirect you anywhere because it has not met it's condition.

In your array `active` is 2, in your if statement your saying `active` cannot be 2. And `org_id` is not 0 and `part_id` is not 0 as you also say it has to be.

Don't see what the problem is. If you're expecting to be redirected, then you have done something wrong in your code.

And if you want it to redirect to `index.php`, then you have to write

```
header('location:index.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data, this is working as expected:

```
<?php

$data =
[
    'notify'  => 'OK',
    'user'    => 'werker@company.com',
    'user_id' => 346,
    'fnln'    => 'test2',
    'type'    => 4,
    'org_id'  => 108,
    'part_id' => 79,
    'active'  => 2
];

if (
       $data['active']  != 2
    && $data['org_id']  == 0
    && $data['part_id'] == 0
)
{
    echo 'Redirect here.';
} else {
    echo 'No redirect.';
}
```

Output:

```
No redirect.
```

Why do you expect otherwise?

The first conditional `$data['active']  != 2` will evaluate to false with your given data sample above.  It will short circuit there with no further checks, so the wider conditional will evaluate to false.